# php composer windows install

Tags: php, windows-installer, composer-php

I want to install composer and run it's command but i always get error bellow:

> Connection Error [ERR_CONNECTION]: Unable to connect to
>   getcomposer.org
>       Request to https://getcomposer.org/installer failed with errors:
>       SSL: Handshake timed out. Failed to enable crypto. Failed to open stream: operation failed

what should i do?
i previously can do any thing but suddenly i get error and i don't change any thing!

Comment: try [a manual download](https://getcomposer.org/download/). If that doesn't work, take [a look at this issue report](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3611), seems to be related. This question is considered off-topic for SO BTW (Read the help section): it's not a coding problem, but a question about a tool or library. Those questions are not what this site is for

Comment: [This page](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3611) is not my answer. I am not behind proxy.what should I do 
please help me. I really need your answer

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it could be a network issue or it's a misconfiguration of some sort.

I would suggest to check the PHP SSL settings.

1. make sure the PHP extensions `php_openssl` and `php_curl` are enabled.
2. check that your `php.ini` has cainfo and cafile properly defined:

   ```
   curl.cainfo=/path/to/ssl-certs/ca-bundle.crt
   openssl.cafile=/path/to/ssl-certs/ca-bundle.crt
   ```

   If certs are missing: download a cert bundle from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and save as `ca-bundle.crt`.
3. check and raise `default_socket_timeout` in `php.ini`

   - its 60 by default, so lets say maybe 120. that depends on your connection.